# How to install hook in server?

Tags: php, linux, bitnami

I use Bitnami for local webserver I want try [this system](http://doubleleft.github.io/hook-userguide/Getting-started/How-to-use/).
But I have no experience with this script, I want understand how I can install it on my localhost. The documentation describe:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doubleleft/hook/master/scripts/install.sh | bash
```

how I should execute this command? Someone could explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here

If you have installed an AMP Stack from Bitnami, you have to load the stack environment.

If you are using Bitnami Cloud Hosting, a virtual machine or a cloud server, the Stack environment is loaded by default and the steps below are unnecessary.

- On Linux

`cd installdir
./installdir/use_application`

- On Windows

Here is a shortcut in Start -> BitNami Application Stack -> "Application console" or "Use Application Stack"

- On OSX

`cd /Applications/application-version
 ./use_application`

You can learn more about the Bitnami console here:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_AMP_Stacks#How_can_I_run_a_command_in_the_Bitnami_AMP_Stack.3f

Once you load the Bitnami console, you can run the command that you pointed in your post in your terminal and you will install the latest version of hook and hook-cli.

Later, you can follow their documentation in order to run a local server or other operations.